# Text animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a text animation like on this page.
http://www.kikk.be/2016/

When you hover over Main Menu item this menu item starts random animate each latter in this menu titel.

Comment: Check http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/shuffle-letters-effect-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The animation you are talking about, don't even use javascript. You can see this when you disable javascript and visit the site.
My guess would be, that they just use css for the animation and that it is not realy random, but just a set of animation frames played fast.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) is an explanation on how to use css animations in general.
And [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_hover.asp) is an explanation on the hover selector in css which allows you to specify mouseover actions and can be simply used together with the animations.